Movie in which the father reads hip phrases out of a book
I can't remember much about this movie, except the father of the family is reading this book on how to communicate with your teen and he keeps reading these "hip" phrases out of a book in an effort to relate to one of the main characters.  Like, he'd be talking to his son and then flip through a few pages in the book and be like, "Hey, man.  You're really...  bringing me down", and you could tell he's reading that phrase from the book and really has no idea what it means.
It may have been "License To Drive" or "Better Off Dead".  Definitely one of those late 80's/early 90's Hollywood movies with a younger star in the lead role.  Anyone know which movie I'm talking about?

It is indeed Better Off Dead, it happens throughout the movie but here's a clip where it happens:




YES!  Thanks!  It was starting to irritate me that I couldn't remember which movie this was from.  :o)
